# How can I embed an SQLite database into an application?

Tags: android, sqlite, import

I think I have some basic understanding problem so maybe someone's able to help :-)

I'm developing an Android application using Eclipse and this application will make use of a database (only reading from the database will be implemented). The database contains around 4,000 entries i.e. creating and populating the database via source code is not an option. Thus I have created the database in advance with all its records.

But how can I "embed" this database file into my application and then access it? The databse will be around 500 kB in file size. Downloading from a remote server is not an option either as this is not allowed.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I solved that problem by:

1. adding `file.db` into project/assets folder;
2. writing next class:

   ```
   public class LinnaeusDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

       private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Dragonfly.db";
       public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.kan.linnaeus/databases/";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
       private final Context dbContext;

       public LinnaeusDatabase(Context context) {
           super(context, DBActivity.DatabaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
           this.dbContext = context;
           DATABASE_NAME = DBActivity.DatabaseName;
           // checking database and open it if exists
           if (checkDataBase()) {
               openDataBase();
           } else
           {
               try {
                   this.getReadableDatabase();
                   copyDataBase();
                   this.close();
                   openDataBase();

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new Error("Error copying database");
               }
               Toast.makeText(context, "Initial database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }

       private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
           InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
           String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
           OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

           byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           int length;
           while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
               myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
           }

           myOutput.flush();
           myOutput.close();
           myInput.close();
       }

       public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
           String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
           dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
       }

       private boolean checkDataBase() {
           SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
           boolean exist = false;
           try {
               String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
               checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
               SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
           } catch (SQLiteException e) {
               Log.v("db log", "database does't exist");
           }

           if (checkDB != null) {
               exist = true;
               checkDB.close();
           }
           return exist;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 15):

Nice article on ReignDesign blog titled [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115184804/http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). Basically you precreate your database, put it in your assets directory in your apk, and on first use copy to "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/" directory.

Answer (score 10):

I've done this in the past by storing a JSON file in the application in the `res/raw` resources and then loading the file on first load. From there, you can use the bulk insert mode to batch-import entries.  See [my database loader for Units](https://github.com/xxv/Units/blob/64cf7cd02315ef0b08696e4216fefd41152bdb6d/src/info/staticfree/android/units/UnitUsageDBHelper.java#L264) as an example of this technique. One benefit of the `res/raw` style is that you can use the Android resource selecting system to localize the data to different regions, so you could have a different database (or part thereof) for different languages or regions.

You could also put a raw SQL dump in a similar file and load that on first load. You can get the file from the resources by using [openRawResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29). I'd recommend this instead of storing a pre-made sqlite database file to increase compatibility between versions of sqlite, as well as make maintaining the database easier (from an app-development lifecycle POV).

When loading things in bulk, make sure to use transactions, as that'll help speed things up and make the loading more reliable.

Comment: Steve, I like that idea. Do you have a code example online, a blog posting or tutorial?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to some code that uses this technique.

Comment: As far as I get it the JSON file will be stored in a string variable which is then passed to the JSON parse in Android, right? How large may this JSON file/string get? In my application it will be around 250-500 kB.

Comment: Yeah, that could be problematic. In your case, if you want to store it in a format that isn't just a sqlite database, it may make sense to just store it as SQL. I wonder how much of an issue pre-creating the DB would be in regards to binary/version compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

In a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109558/3681880), CommonsWare recommends against the same method proposed by @evilone here (ie, copying the database from assets yourself). Instead you should use the tried and tested [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). I've used it in Android Studio and it works well.

The [directions](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown) are fairly clear. Here are a few key excerpts:

> If you are using the Gradle build system, simply add the following
>   dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
}
```

> Extend `SQLiteAssetHelper` as you would normally do `SQLiteOpenHelper`,
>   providing the constructor with a database name and version number:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Put your database in `assets/databases/northwind.db` (using whatever database name you have).

> The database is made available for use the first time either
>   `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` is called.