# i want some initial data in my database table's one column in sqlite.

Tags: android-studio

i am having one table  with four columns but i want to add some data in category column when application opens. I tried to insert data directly by using insert query but i found this is not the correct way to put initial data.

Comment: can you please post what you have tried

Comment: db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Category VALUES(' ','Shopping',' ',')";
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Category VALUES(' ','Food',' ',')";
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Category VALUES(' ','Travel',' ',')";

Comment: Sorry for late reply..i was stuck somewhere

Comment: This is not even correct syntex for insertion a record in table,please refer this link and check for exception  in insertion

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the 2nd answer at:

[initialize a sqlite database android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108111/initialize-a-sqlite-database-android)

?  What `Suragch` does there is create an array in an xml resource, and then retrieves that array in the `onCreate` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  Then they insert it into the database using `ContentValues.put` and `database.insert`.

Comment: it is not working or i am doing wrong .Please check my code

Comment: public static final String CATEGORY_SQL = "CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY+" ("+ID+" varchar, "+TITLE+" varchar, "+DESCRIPTION+" varchar, "+TYPE+" varchar)";

Comment: ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        String[] myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_array);
        for (String item : myArray) {
            values.put(CategoryModelDAO.ID, DEFAULT_FIRST_COLUMN);
            values.put(CategoryModelDAO.TITLE, item);
            values.put(CategoryModelDAO.DESCRIPTION, DEFAULT_THIRD_COLUMN);
            values.put(CategoryModelDAO.TYPE, DEFAULT_FOURTH_COLUMN);
            db.insert(CategoryModelDAO.CATEGORY, null, values);

Comment: this is array created in resources       <resources>

    <string-array name="my_array">

        <item>Clothing</item>
        <item>Eating Out</item>
        <item>Entertainment</item>
        <item>Food</item>
        <item>General</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>