# error insert data into database

Tags: android

i try inserting data into my sqlite table, but i have a trouble inserted

my error log

```
02-12 10:55:47.927: V/aaaa(1273): zaza
02-12 10:55:47.927: I/Database(1273): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: users
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273): Error inserting username=zaza
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users: , while compiling: INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?);
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at com.example.database.DatabaseMain$1$1.onClick(DatabaseMain.java:63)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 10:55:47.957: E/Database(1273):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am inserting use custom dialog with edittext, my editttext i show on `log.v` is show

but why can't inserted my data?

my code

```
public class DatabaseMain extends Activity {

    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    //private CursorAdapter dataSource;

    //put the table name and column in constants
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "username";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database_main);
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper (this);
        //dbHelper.openDataBase();
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ListView listdata= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = DatabaseMain.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View v1 =inflater.inflate(R.layout.username , null) ;

                new AlertDialog.Builder(DatabaseMain.this)
                    .setTitle("input your name:")
                    .setView(v1)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                            EditText name = (EditText)v1.findViewById(R.id.name);


                            String your_name = name.getText().toString();
                            values.put(COLUMN_NAME,name);

                                    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

            }
        }); 
    }


}
```

i am using database from file then i put on folder assets then i am copy with this code

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "MyDb";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    private static DataBaseHelper sInstance = null;


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{


        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }
    public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
        return myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }


    public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
        myDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
    }


    public void delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {

        myDataBase.delete(table, where, null);

    }


    public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {

        myDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);

    }
    public void sqlCommand(String command) {
        myDataBase.execSQL(command);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public static DataBaseHelper instance() {
        /*
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DataBaseHelper();
        }
        */
        return sInstance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your `users` table plain doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: i am using database from file then i put on folder assets then i am copy, on file explorer data/data/com.example.database be a my database

Comment: how to look my table into database on file explorer data/data/com.example.database?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I don't understand at all what you're saying or asking.

Comment: i am copying my database file into folder asset to data/data/com.example.database then my table can't copying, how to copying my database.sqlite into my application?and how to insert my database.sqlite after copying into application?

Comment: You could check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627037/how-can-i-embed-an-sqlite-database-into-an-application) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table, before inserting into it:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users: , while compiling: INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?);
```

Something like:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users(username varchar);");
```

Comment: i am using database from file then i put on folder assets then i am copy, on file explorer data/data/com.example.database be a my database

Comment: how to look my table into database on file explorer data/data/com.example.database?

Answer (score 0):

it says table name Users is not there in database,  If you already added create table statement for users like `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE STATEMENT FOR USERS Table");`, after creating your database. I will suggest You to `uninstall` your app and `reinstall` it again. it will in term will create database with newly added tables too.

Comment: i am using table from file then i put on folder assets then i am copy, on file explorer data/data/com.example.database be a my database

Comment: how to look my table into database on file explorer data/data/com.example.database?